# Tailwind css is not working in vercel after depoly

Tags: css, json, deployment, vercel, tailwind-ui

I have created a website that works well on local hosts but in vercel deployment output.css is empty.

here is code of package json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "scripts":{
"build":"npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css "
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

here is tailwing.config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}","./public/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

please help

Comment: I am assuming you are using the `Tailwind CLI` to compile the stylesheet, however, tailwind is almost always used as a dev dependency. Instead of building the content at the server(vercel), try building the css using `npm run build` and pushing the compiled css to the repo (and then to vercel).

Opting for Tailwind CLI means that you're probably not using any front-end frameworks. What's your developmental workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is in javascript based on the content you have included in your tailwind.config file. Let's assume you are using npm, try running **npm run build** and if this doesn't fix the problem follow up with the errors that will be displayed. Also, Vercel gives you a record of the entire deployment which shows where the error is happening and you can debug from there if you show this record it would be easier to appoint a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: guys in my case, the problem i had was a badly implemented middleware.ts that I grabbed from clerkjs, it was not wrong on clerkjs, it was wrong after my modifications, which I was able to debug and see that the middleware with my changes was preventing CSS from loading